# How can I call a Java method using the Terminal?

Tags: java

have a problem with JAVA when try to call a method if the main execute from TERMINAL.

i have a simple Class A

```
public class A{
   public static int promedio(ArrayList<Integer> array) {
       int sum=0,prom=0;
       for(int i=0 ; i < array.size() ; i++) {
           sum+=array.get(i);}
       prom = sum/array.size();
       return prom;
   }
}
```

And Iam try to call method promedio() from Class B

```
public class B{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       
        //Convert to int the string from args
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            int StrToInt= Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            array.add(StrToInt);
            }
        //call method class A
        int returnPromedio = A.promedio(array);

        System.out.println("Prom: "+returnPromedio);
        
        }
}
```

when try to run from TERMINAL with
 `java B.java 200 100`

Get this error:

```
B.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        int returnPromedio = A.promedio(array);
                             ^
  symbol:   variable A
  location: class B
1 error
error: compilation failed
```

What I can do to run this code from TERMINAL,  thanks everyone!!

Comment: both classes need to be compiled. A isn't recognized as a class during your execution. Also, the .java is only needed when you compile, it should be java B 200 100

Comment: Did you build the code before launching?

Comment: @Stultuske `java File.java` will actually work (from Java 9 IIRC). Try it, it's great for quick scripts :)

Comment: If `A` is in a different package than `B`, you will have to import it in `B.java`. Hope all that is taken care of.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works. Compile it and then change your dir in the command line to where your classes are located. Run this command in the screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I copied your classes, compiled both of them, and executed from command line as you mentioned.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a try to run B.java on src folder...

I need to run B.class from bin folder,

Finally move to bin folder and run:

```
java B 200 100
```

[image: Works OK!!]